# Learning about Entropy, notation question: is $P(X)$ a random variable?

Tags: probability, entropy

**Background**

I'm taking a first year probability course and I've gotten reasonably comfortable calculating $E[g(X)]$ using LOTUS. Now I'm learning about Entropy and for the first time I'm encountering a situation where $P(X)$ is in $g(X)$.

**Entropy**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)):

$$H(X) = E[I(X)] = E[-\log(P(X))]$$

**Question 1:** Is it correct to think of $P(X)$ as a function of $X$, and is therefore a RV itself? I'm wondering how to formally define $P(X)$... my attempt:

$$ P(X) = g(X) = \left\{
\begin{array}{11}
p_1 & \text{with } Pr(P(X) = p_1) = p_1\\
p_2 & \text{with } Pr(P(X) = p_2) = p_2\\
\vdots \\
p_n & \text{with } Pr(P(X) = p_n) = p_n\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

Like I said I'm used to evaluating $E[g(X)]$ but it's just weirding me out that $g(X)$ is the pmf of $X$.

**Question 2:**  If $P(X)$ is a RV... I'm wondering if the value of $E[P(X)] = \sum p(x)p(x)$ ever comes up or is studied. I did some searches for it and outside of hmwk exercises it doesn't seem that interesting.

Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Define $p(x)=P(X=x)$. Then $Y=p(X)$ is a RV. Just as it is when you have measurable $f(x)$ and define $Y=f(X)$, though it might seem strange to use the PMF itself, at first, yes. Indeed the expectation of $Y=p(X)$ is not as useful as the expectation of $-\log Y$, which garnered the term *entropy* of $X$.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Thanks for your thoughts, that is very helpful!